# How to filter records based on more than 1 property and get count

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a data in my controller like that:

```
$scope.items = [
{
  id: "0",
  name: "Nurse1",
  icon: "rooms_nurse.svg",
  type: "nurse",
  location: build-A
},
{
  id: "1",
  name: "Nurse2",
  icon: "rooms_nurse.svg",
  type: "nurse",
  location: build-A
},
{
  id: "1",
  name: "Dr",
  icon: "rooms_dr.svg",
  type: "Dr",
  location: build-B
},
{
  id: "2",
  name: "Dr",
  icon: "rooms_dr.svg",
  type: "Dr",
  location: build-B
}]
```

What i want that to filter this data on the basis of location and type and also find result count like how many nurses/Dr are in each location:

```
$scope.items = [
{
count:2
  icon: "rooms_nurse.svg",
  type: "nurse",
  location: build-A
},
{

  count:2
  icon: "rooms_dr.svg",
  type: "Dr",
  location: build-B
},
 ......    
]
```

I know there is a filter service but it only work for one property

```
   $scope.content = $filter('countBy')($scope.items,'type');
```

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply create a custom filter:

```
angular.module('filterMore', []).
  filter('countBy', function() {
    return function(type,location) {
      var out = [];
      // Filter logic here, adding matches to the out var.
      return out;
    }
  });
```